# Normalizing after standard scaling

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I am a bit confused about this post:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-data-transforms-for-time-series-forecasting/#comment-483967

Dr. Brownlee advises on normalizing the dataset after performing standardization but I don't understand why is it needed?

Comment: Do either one or the other. It makes no sense to do both. Whenever possible, try to work with scale-invariant models

Comment: @David that's what I have been reading about and I cannot find a good explanation on why he advises on doing both.